# How do you tell apt to use files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Tags: apt, repository

I added a repo by putting a file in

```
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and then i did an

```
 apt-get update.
```

However it didn't do anything with that repo.  I then noticed that it didn't appear to be including any of the repos in that directory.  Only stuff in /etc/apt/sources.list seem to be noticed by apt-get.  All the files in the directory end in .list and contain something like:

```
 virtualbox.list

      deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib

 pj-assis-ppa-oneiric.list

      deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pj-assis/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
      deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pj-assis/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Do I need to put some sort of include statement in /etc/apt/sources.list?

I'm using kubuntu 11.10.

Comment: You can dump the current apt configuration by using `apt-config dump`. There should be a line that says `Dir::Etc::sourceparts "sources.list.d";`. Maybe this helps for further investigation.

Comment: You did `apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get update`? How did you notice or confirm that, that repository is not enabled?

Comment: just copy the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: So the problem seemed to be that I had a package installed from one of the normal apt repos and I wanted it to update with a version from one of the new repos.  Apparently this is not possible.  I had to uninstall the packages in question and then install with all of the normal repos commented out.  I'm still not sure why when you do an apt-get update, that none of these new repos have their urls displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be that I had a package installed from one of the normal apt repos and I wanted it to update with a version from one of the new repos. Apparently this is not possible. I had to uninstall the packages in question and then install with all of the normal repos commented out. I'm still not sure why when you do an apt-get update, that none of these new repos have their urls displayed.

Comment: You do not answer your own question. What you did here is not very clear, doesn't relate to your question and probably it should have been done by [apt pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning).

Comment: I only can tell you that this fixed the problem I was having when I asked the question.  The other "answer" clearly didn't read my question and was totally useless. This is what worked for me.  I don't know if it will work for anyone else.  I assume it was some bug in ubuntu 11 that caused it not to use updated packages from additional repos. It seems to not be an issue in ubuntu 12 or 13.

Answer (score 11):

The names of files in `/etc/sources.list.d` must end in `.list`, if they are to be included as software sources.

As the [man page of sources.list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) says:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>    The package resource list is used to locate archives of the package
>    distribution system in use on the system. At this time, this manual
>    page documents only the packaging system used by the Debian GNU/Linux
>    system. This control file is /etc/apt/sources.list.
>
>    The source list is designed to support any number of active sources and
>    a variety of source media. The file lists one source per line, with the
>    most preferred source listed first. The format of each line is: type
>    uri args The first item, type determines the format for args.  uri is a
>    Universal Resource Identifier (URI), which is a superset of the more
>    specific and well-known Universal Resource Locator, or URL. The rest of
>    the line can be marked as a comment by using a #.
> ```
>
> **SOURCES.LIST.D**
>
> ```
>    The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add
>    sources.list entries in separate files. The format is the same as for
>    the regular sources.list file. File names need to end with .list and
>    may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_),
>    hyphen (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice
>    that it has ignored a file if the file doesn't match a pattern in the
>    Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in this case it will be
>    silently ignored.
> ```

**Taking an example from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409235/creating-a-file-inside-etc-apt-sources-list-d)**, suppose you wanted to install *chef (from opscode)*, what you'd do is:

- Create and open a file named `opscode.list`:

```
    sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list
```

- Add the required line and save the file:

```
    deb http://apt.opscode.com/ oneiric main
```

The above steps can be combined to make a single command:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.opscode.com/ onereic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list'
```

**Note:** The command contains `onereic` because the codename of the Ubuntu you're using is **Onereic**. Had you been using **Precise** (12.04), you'd have writter `precise`.

Comment: Have you read the OP? He does all these steps.

Comment: He did not specify, what file he added.

Comment: He did give two names (virtualbox.list and another one)