# E: Malformed entry 11 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I have tried to install qt-5 but I got

```
E: Malformed entry 11 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 11 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

My `sources.list`

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main 
deb-src http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                           UNOFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C6DAEA80
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/boomaga/ppa/ubuntu xenial main # Boomaga PPA - https://launchpad.net/~boomaga/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

## Run this command: wget -q -O - http://dano.cu.cc/1Aci9Qp | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update
deb http://repo.daniil.it lenny main # Daniil's Bash Video Download - http://daniil.it

## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 614C4B38
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial main # Gimp PPA - https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp

## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B1510FD
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial main # GNOME3 Extra Apps PPA - https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

## Run this command: wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

## Run this command: wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main # Google Earth - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  247510BE
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu xenial main # Mozilla Daily Build Team PPA - http://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa

## Run this command: sudo wget -O - http://apt.mucommander.com/apt.key | sudo apt-key add - 
deb http://apt.mucommander.com stable main non-free contrib   # muCommander - http://www.mucommander.com/

## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
deb [arch=i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam # Steam for Linux - http://store.steampowered.com/about/

## Run this command: curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release # Syncthing - https://syncthing.net/
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
canonical_partner.list       google.list.save     staticfloat-ubuntu-julia-deps-xenial.list          vivaldi.list.save
canonical_partner.list.save  hexinator.list       staticfloat-ubuntu-julia-deps-xensave
google.list                  libdvdcss.list.save  vivaldi.list
ial.list.save     webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
google-chrome.list           hexinator.list.save  staticfloat-ubuntu-juliareleases-xenial.list       webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
google-chrome.list.save      libdvdcss.list       staticfloat-ubuntu-juliareleases-xenial.list.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the problem:

```
deb-src http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates
```

You're missing the component section of this line, it should look something like:

```
deb-src http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe
```

Your sources.list is missing many important sections, including security updates, I recommend you leave the `/etc/apt/sources.list` alone and put your customizations in a .list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` so you don't break the default file.

See also:

- [How do you tell apt to use files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190149/how-do-you-tell-apt-to-use-files-in-etc-apt-sources-list-d)
- [Do files at /etc/apt/sources.list.d need to have an extension '.list'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82825/do-files-at-etc-apt-sources-list-d-need-to-have-an-extension-list)

Comment: How to put my customizations,can you send any link?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a apt-get update to see if it helps.
If not access the file with vim/vi and go to the prompt ( ESC and :) and type: 'set number' to see the number of the lines. Check the line 11 and if there's something wrong with that. You can try to comment this line and run a apt-get update again to see if that helps.